# How to get triangle count and local clustering coefficient of nodes in edge lists stored in dictionary using Python?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a dictionary that contain many edge lists with below format:

```
{'0': [[0, 2],
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]],
 '1': [[1, 6],
  [2, 6],
  [3, 4],
  [0, 3],
  [2, 4]]}
```

I'd like to first get the total # of triangles for each edge list 0 & 1.

Then, for each node in edge list 0 & 1, I'd like to get the # of triangles that each node belongs to and its local clustering coefficient.

The result format could be dictionary, lists or pandas data frame.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data doesn't actually have any triangles (complete subgraphs on three nodes) in your provided data, but here's an example with an additional edgelist with them. Note, the `networkx.from_edgelist` function accepts an edgelist as a list of tuples rather than a list of lists so I had to change them. The `networkx.triangles` function returns a dictionary keyed by each node that provides the count of triangles that use this node. We can sum the values of that dict and divide by three to determine the actual number of triangles [see docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.triangles.html).

```
import networkx as nx
dat = {'0': [[0, 2],[1, 2],
             [3, 4],[5, 6]],
       '1': [[1, 6],[2, 6],
             [3, 4],[0, 3],[2, 4]],
       # adding a graph with two triangles
       '2': [[0,1],[1,2],
             [2,0],[3,4],
             [4,5],[5,3]]}

graphs = {key:nx.from_edgelist([(v[0],v[1]) for v in value]) for key,value in dat.items()}

# count number of triangles per node
node_triangle_counts = {key:nx.triangles(graph) for key,graph in graphs.items()}
print(node_triangle_counts)
# {'0': {0: 0, 2: 0, 1: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0},
#  '1': {1: 0, 6: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 0: 0},
#  '2': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}}

# sum the node counts and divide by three because each triangle is counted for all three nodes in the triangle
num_triangles_per_graph = {key:sum(val_dict.values()) / 3
                           for key,val_dict in node_triangle_counts.items()}

# {'0': 0, '1': 0, '2': 2}
```